# Creating map to show user location and annotations programmatically in Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, mapkit

I'm trying to replicate what I had in another project where I used storyboards using only code. The view controller I'm struggling with is the map view controller.

I'm trying to create a map which shows the user location, zooms to a suitable level around that location on launching and then allow the user to drop a pin on the map which will have a circle overlay around the location of the pin.

I have managed to create the map and show user location, but am struggling setting the region to zoom on the location when the map launches. I have been struggling with this for a couple of days.

I know I need to use CLlocation2D somewhere, but am not sure where/how to use this at the moment.

I also tried to setup my map using functions, code so far is below (it's a botch job from different sources trying to make it fit my goal, so apologies if it's messy)

```
> import UIKit 
> import MapKit 
> import CoreLocation
>
> class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate,
> CLLocationManagerDelegate {

>     var mapView: MKMapView!
>     var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
>     
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>         super.viewDidLoad()
>  
>         setupMapView()
> 
>     }
>     
>     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
>         super.viewWillAppear(animated)
>         
>     }
> 
>     func setupMapView() {
>         let mapView = MKMapView()
> 
>         let leftMargin:CGFloat = 0
>         let topMargin:CGFloat = 0
>         let mapWidth:CGFloat = view.frame.size.width
>         let mapHeight:CGFloat = view.frame.size.height
> 
>         mapView.frame = CGRect(x: leftMargin, y: topMargin, width: mapWidth, height: mapHeight)
> 
>         mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
>         mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
>         mapView.isScrollEnabled = true
>         mapView.showsCompass = true
>         mapView.showsScale = true
>         mapView.showsUserLocation = true
>         
>         let noLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
>         let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
>         let viewLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMake(noLocation, span)
>         
>         
>         mapView.setRegion(viewLocation, animated: true)
>         print(viewLocation)
> 
>         view.addSubview(mapView)
>     }
>  
>     //add function to create circle overlay
> 
> //    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { //       
> super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() //        // Dispose of any resources
> that can be recreated. //    }
>     
> 
>     /*
>     // MARK: - Navigation
> 
>     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
>     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
>         // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
>         // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
>     }
>     */
> 
> }
```

For the pin, in storyboard I used

> @IBAction func pinDrop(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)

but am not sure how to translate this to programatic code.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Add long press like this

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.addAnnotation(_:)))

self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

//

get coordinates of press

```
@objc func addAnnotation(_ gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer)
{

   if gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.began
    {
      return
    }
     let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.mapView)
     let newCoordinates = self.mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: self.mapView)

}
```

//

```
 let noLocation =  self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate

 let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)

 let viewLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMake(noLocation, span)

 mapView.setRegion(viewLocation, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried this, but get the error - Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I'm guessing it's because there's no initial long press gesture so that is causing the process to crash? I also put let longPress... within setupMapView, is this correct? I tried in both the function and ViewDidLoad and get the same error in both cases

Comment: remove let here **let mapView = MKMapView()**

Comment: that worked, thanks! - just so I understand, why did the 'let' cause the problem?

Comment: because with let you declare a local mapView variable other than the one declared here  `var mapView: MKMapView!` which is deallocated after `viewDidLoad` executed leaving that out var nil and cause a crash when you long press but when you remove let the initalization happens for that out var

Comment: Ok, I follow. Do you have any idea of how to set the region? I’m thinking that I can put mapView.setRegion in the setupMapView function, but don’t know how to access the user location. At the moment the region is not where the user location is.

Comment: You can use `self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate`

Comment: That makes sense, and returns a coordinate for the user location. But when I try and set it as mapView region I get an error saying Cannot convert value of type ‘CLLocationCoordinate2D’ to specified type ‘MKCoordinateRegion’. Is there anyway to convert CLLocation2d coordinates to MKcoordinate? - that’s what I’m assuming I need to do